# unify four csv files in one csv using keyword

Tags: bash, csv

I need to join 4 csv files using the first column of each file as keyword. I have used sort but it doesn't run in this case.

The structure of each file is simple,

```
file 1
London,7,10
Madrid,10,20
Paris,7,14

file 2
London,10,15
Madrid,10,16
Paris,11,16

file 3
London,6,12
Madrid,7,14
Paris,8,15

file 4
London,7,14
Madrid,8,14
Paris,9,15
```

and I need

```
ending file 
London,7,10,10,16,6,12,7,14
Madrid,10,20,10,16,7,14,8,14
Paris,7,14,11,16,8,15,9,15
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily do it using `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]","$2","$3}END{for (i in arr) print i arr[i]}' file1 file2 file3 file4
London,7,10,10,15,6,12,7,14
Madrid,10,20,10,16,7,14,8,14
Paris,7,14,11,16,8,15,9,15
```

Comment: Awk runs well but something in my files is not correct, because, after using awk -F.....I have the following result                                                                    London, 7,10 and in a second line 10,16, and in a third line 6,12...and the same for Madrid and Paris

Comment: @EnricAgudPique Did you use the exact script as above. If so would you please provide which awk version are you using. Tested it working on gnu awk

Comment: @nu11po1n73R I use [enric@localhost ~]$ awk -W version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
Maybe the problem comes from the csv files, but they have the form I show above...

Comment: it is solved! I had a problem with Windows carriage returns, i have used tr -d '\r' < infile.csv > outfile.csv in order to delete it. It runs great now awk!

Comment: @EnricAgudPique Glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` program. It can only do two at a time, so you'll need to chain it.

```
join -t, test.1 test.2 | join -t, - test.3 | join -t, - test.4
```

The files need to be sorted by the joining field (1), if they're not, you need to pass through `sort` too:

```
join -t, <(sort test.1) <(sort test.2) | join -t, - <(sort test.3) | join -t, - <(sort test.4)
```